# Split an input for different command and combine the result

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, pipe, process-substitution

I know how to combine the result of different command

```
paste -t',' <(commanda) <(commandb)
```

I know pipe same input to different command

```
cat myfile | tee >(commanda) >(commandb)
```

Now how to combine these command? So that I can do

```
cat myfile | tee >(commanda) >(commandb) | paste -t',' resulta resultb
```

Say I have a file

myfile:

```
1
2
3
4
```

I want to make a new file

```
1 4 2
2 3 4
3 2 6
4 1 8
```

I used

```
cat myfile | tee >(tac) >(awk '{print $1*2}') | paste
```

would gives me result vertically, where I really want paste them in horizontal order.

Comment: you may have to write two streams to seperate name pipes , and combine them with a monitor programme .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you tee to multiple process substitutions, you're not guaranteed to get the output in any particular order, so you'd better stick with

```
paste -t',' <(commanda < file) <(commandb < file)
```

Assuming `cat myfile` stands for some expensive pipeline, I think you'll have to store the output, either in a file or a variable:

```
output=$( some expensive pipeline )
paste -t',' <(commanda <<< "$output") <(commandb <<< "$output")
```

Using your example:

```
output=$( seq 4 )
paste -d' ' <(cat <<<"$output") <(tac <<<"$output") <(awk '$1*=2' <<<"$output")
```

```
1 4 2
2 3 4
3 2 6
4 1 8
```

---

Another thought: FIFOs, and a single pipeline

```
mkfifo resulta resultb
seq 4 | tee  >(tac > resulta) >(awk '$1*=2' > resultb) | paste -d ' ' - resulta resultb
rm resulta resultb
```

```
1 4 2
2 3 4
3 2 6
4 1 8
```

Comment: can i use sth like /dev/fd/3-9?

Answer (score 4):

The `yash` shell has unique features (*pipeline redirection* and *process redirection*) that make that easier there:

```
cat myfile | (
  exec 3>>|4
  tee /dev/fd/5 5>(commanda >&3 3>&-) 3>&- |
    commandb 3>&- |
    paste -d , /dev/fd/4 - 3>&-
)
```

`3>>|4` (*pipeline redirection*) creates a pipe where the writing end is on fd 3 and the reading end on fd 4.

`3>(commanda>&3)` is *process redirection*, a bit like ksh/zsh/bash process substitution but just does the redirection and doesn't substitute with the `/dev/fd/n`. `ksh`'s `>(cmd)` is more or less the same as `yash`'s `n>(cmd) /dev/fd/n` (there `n` is a file descriptor chosen by `ksh` on which you have no control).

Answer (score 3):

With `zsh`:

```
pee() (
  n=0 close_in= close_out= inputs=() outputs=()
  merge_command=$1; shift
  for cmd do
    eval "coproc $cmd $close_in $close_out"

    exec {i}<&p {o}>&p
    inputs+=($i) outputs+=($o)
    eval i$n=$i o$n=$o
    close_in+=" {i$n}<&-" close_out+=" {o$n}>&-"
    ((n++))
  done
  coproc :
  read -p
  eval tee /dev/fd/$^outputs $close_in "> /dev/null &
    " exec $merge_command /dev/fd/$^inputs $close_out
)
```

Then use as:

```
$ echo abcd | pee 'paste -d,' 'tr a A' 'tr b B' 'tr c C'
Abcd,aBcd,abCd
```

That's adapted from [this other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/66875/22565) where you'll find some detailed explanations and hints at the limitations (beware of deadlocks!).

Answer (score 0):

For your particular example there should be no need for `paste` and the rest. It is often true that when we encounter a limit with the standard toolset it is because what we want to do one way can be done another. Such as:

```
set 1 2 3 4
while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]
do    echo "$1" "$#" "$(($1*2))"
shift;done
```

...which prints...

```
1 4 2
2 3 4
3 2 6
4 1 8
```

You can get a file with contents like you mention into your shell `"$@"` array like...

```
set -f; IFS='
'; set -- $(cat)
```

And to validate the arg values in a loop like the one above you can change the initial test a bit...

```
while { [ "$1" -eq "${1-1}" ] ;} 2>&"$((2+!$#))"
do    echo "$1" "$#" "$(($1*2))"
shift;done  3>/dev/null >outfile
```

...which prints an error to stderr only if a line read in with `set -- $(cat)` contains a line which does not consist entirely of a single integer.