# Do any shells generalize the notion of pipes to multiple parallel pipelines? Would supporting it require changes to the OS kernel?

Tags: pipe, fifo, gnu-parallel

Quite often, when working on the command line, I find myself specifying the same operation on a bunch of different instances specified by some input stream, and then wanting to recombine their outputs in some specific way.

Two use cases from yesterday:

1. I wanted to see the Subjects of a bunch of SSL certificates bundled in a PEM file.

   ```
    cat mypemfile.crt |
    (openssl x509 -noout -text | fgrep Subject:)
   ```

   only shows me the first one.  I need to split out the certificates and run the same command on each of them, then concatenate the results. `csplit` can split them, but to files only. This is a hassle.

   Why can't I just say

   ```
    cat mypemfile.crt |
    csplit-tee '/BEGIN/ .. /END/' |
    on-each ( openssl x509 -noout -text | fgrep Subject: ) |
    merge --cat
   ```

   ?
2. We run a JupyterHub instance that splits off notebook servers as Docker containers.
   I want to watch their timestamped logs.  It's easy enough for one container:

   ```
    sudo docker logs -t -f $container_id
   ```

   (The `-t` adds a timestamp, and the `-f` keeps the pipe open, like `tail -f`.)

   It's easy enough to list the logs of all containers, sorted by timestamps:

   ```
    sudo docker ps | awk '{print $1}' |
    while read container_id
    do
      sudo docker logs -t $container_id
    done |
    sort
   ```

   or

   ```
    sudo docker ps | awk '{print $1}' |
    xargs -n1 sudo docker logs -t |
    sort
   ```

   or

   ```
    sudo docker ps | awk '{print $1}' |
    parallel sudo docker logs -t {} |
    sort
   ```

   but none of that will let me use the `-f` option to watch the logs as they come in.

   Why can't I just use

   ```
    sudo docker ps | awk '{print $1}' |
    csplit-tee /./ |
    on-each (xargs echo | sudo docker logs -t -f) |
    merge --line-by-line --lexicographically
   ```

   or

   ```
    sudo docker ps | awk '{print $1}' |
    parallel --multipipe sudo docker logs -t -f {} |
    merge --line-by-line --lexicographically
   ```

   ?

Clearly, this requires

1. Specific shell support. Maybe we'd need a distinct "multi-pipe" symbol.
2. New tools (`csplit-tee`, `on-each` and `merge`) that split and merge pipelines.
3. A fixed convention for how to specify, within tools, arbitrarily many input and output file descriptors such that this shell will treat them as parallel pipelines.

Has this been done? Or something equivalent that I can apply to my use cases?

Is it feasible without specific kernel support? I know the kernel typically has a fixed maximum number of open file descriptors, but an implementation can work around that by not blindly trying to open them all at once.

Is it feasible, knowing that [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) is feasible?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what `csplit-tee`, `oneach` and `merge` are supposed to do, but your `openssl` example seems to be doing `awk -v cmd="openssl x509 -noout -text | fgrep Subject:" '/BEGIN/ { p = 1 } p { print | cmd } /END/{close (cmd)}' mypemfile.crt`

Comment: This is well above kernel level if I understand you correctly. Programs write to `stdout` (handle 1) and other programs read from `stdin` (handle 0). A pipe connects `stdout` from process to `stdin` by a different one. Handling that is usually done by the shell (parent process). BTW `lsof` can help visualise this.

Comment: Also, PowerShell with its object-oriented system can do some complex things easily compared to your run-of-the-mill text-based shells.

Comment: That doesn't need any kernel extension and a T+Y program which splits an input, filters it through n filter processes and then joins back could be easily written in any C, perl, etc. But it cannot be generalized beyond some stupid demos, because it will run in the same deadlock+buffering issues that coprococesses (and similar features) have run into. Just do the first part with `tee` outputting to temporary files, and after all the parallel writers have finished, merge the temporary files. For the examples you're giving, that's more than enough.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tee + cat: use an output several times and then concatenate results](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66853/tee-cat-use-an-output-several-times-and-then-concatenate-results)

Comment: Yes, this is helpful, thanks - the  `pee` utility is a bit like my imaginary `merge`. I'm still hoping to find something more like my imaginary examples.

Comment: I don't see why deadlock would be a problem. Temporary files don't cut it in general because they aren't streams, and dealing files creates additional complexity I don't want to bother with. The answers given show that I can avoid that already e.g. with GNU parallel.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU Parallel:

```
cat mypemfile.crt |
  parallel --pipe -N1 --recstart '-----BEGIN' 'openssl x509 -noout -text | fgrep Subject:'
```

Untested:

```
sudo docker ps | awk '{print $1}' |
  sudo parallel -j0 --lb docker logs -t -f {}

sudo docker ps | awk '{print $1}' |
  sudo parallel -j0 --tag --lb docker logs -t -f {}
```

Comment: Yes, I guess `parallel` would resolve the multiple parallel process creation. The tricky part would be the output pipe. In theory, nothing will prevent lines from different processus to be interleaved. If the bottleneck is in the last process, the parallel processes will be paused waiting for the pipe to be read and what is read could be a part of what was written by a process and the whole written line interleaved with others. But I guess that casual needs doesn’t troublesome.

Comment: @FrédéricLoyer --lb = interleaved - but only complete lines. Remove --lb to avoid the interleaving: It will only output when the job completes. -u = mix lines - half lines may come from different processes.

Comment: I think shell support would be more intuitive and "Unixy", but this is very compact; clearly I should explore GNU parallel more.

Comment: @reinierpost May I recommend https://www.lulu.com/shop/ole-tange/gnu-parallel-2018/paperback/product-23558902.html or https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.1146014

Comment: Thanks, I'll consider it! That link is broken now, but this one works for me: https://www.lulu.com/en/us/shop/ole-tange/gnu-parallel-2018/paperback/product-1jq6qq4v.html

Answer (score 0):

No the shell can't do that. A pipe is just a stream from a source to a destination, usually in different processes.

Let's look at your first example:

```
cat mypemfile.crt |
(openssl x509 -noout -text | fgrep Subject:)
```

You want the input file to be split along lines containing BEGIN and END, but `cat` doesn't care about the content, and pipes don't have out of bound indication of record separators anyway.

You could achieve this with specific conventions in the source and destination of a pipe, but it would remove the main advantage of a pipe, to be able to combine programs as building blocks for tasks that were not anticipated by their authors.

In this specific example, it would be much easier to modify `openssl` to process multiple certificates in one stream than it would be to modify `openssl` to process multiple stream AND modify `cat` to provide these multiple streams.

Comment: I know the shell can't do it - hence my question whether anyone has extended a shell so it can. Generic support for this fits the "Unix toolbox philosophy".